# What could be a field that has an infinite dimension over $\mathbb C$?

Tags: field-theory

We know that a any finite dimensional field over R is isomorphic to C. However what about infinite dimensional ones? Are they known to exist?

Comment: If you mean infinite dimensional _algebraic_ extensions, no, but transcendental extensions such as $\mathbb{C}(t)$, rational functions in one variable over $\mathbb{C}$, are infinite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

> **Hint:** $\Bbb F=\left\{\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}:0\neq q(x),p(x)\in\Bbb C[x]\right\}$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb C$.